Prototype issue whith Firebase cloud functions
I have an issue while writing Firebase cloud functions.
Here is the relevant code I have for a cloud function:
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
.....

admin.initializeApp();

exports.myCloudFunc = onRequest({cors: ["*"]}, (req, res) => {
  let dbStr:string;
  .....
  const dbRef = admin.database().ref(dbStr);
  dbRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    const snpsv = snapshot.val();
  
    if ((snpsv === undefined) || (snpsv == null)) {
      jsonResult = {"Error": "No data found."};
      res.send(jsonResult);
    }
  
    const reviewType = snapshot.child("revwType").val();
  
    // Beginning of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE
    const db2ndRef = admin.database().ref(reviewType);
    .....
    db2ndRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      const snpsv = snapshot.val();
      .....
    });
    // End of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE
  });
}); /* End of myCloudFunc */

The question I have relates to the part of the code, between these two lines:
// Beginning of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE
// End of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE

The code above works, but instead of having this huge chunk of code, I would like to abstract it away in a function that I would call like this:
// Beginning of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE
jobFunc(reviewType, res);
// End of BIG-CHUNK-OF-CODE

The problem is that I can't figure out the proper prototype for the function:
I tried something like the following, but it does not work:
function jobFunc(dbPath:string, res:Response) {
  .....
} /* End of jobFunc */

I get error messages concerning the type of the parameters.
res:Response

looks wrong.
Does anyone know how to solve this ?
Or is something impossible with what I want to do ?

Your task will be a lot easier if you use get instead of once to query the database.  get returns a promise, so you can use async/await instead of having to deal with callbacks.  That means your jobFunc can also just easily return a promise to await with the results of a query.

@Doug. OK, you may well be right. I need to figure out how to use get instead of once in my cloud function then.
